# homotopy equivalence between graph and sphere and related Euler characteristic

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I saw a question here [The relationship between the Euler characteristic and the fundamental group of finite connected graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142177/the-relationship-between-the-euler-characteristic-and-the-fundamental-group-of-f) saying that :

> Any connected graph is homotopy equivalent to wedge of $S_1$

I've got 3 questions:

1. Why? And for example, for a connected graph like a hexagon or $K_{3,3}$, how to write it as wedge of $S_1$?
2. Euler characteristic is a characteristic class on the vector bundle of a manifold. But for a graph, how can we define such a vector bundle on a graph which corresponds to its Euler characteristic class?
3. For cellular complex, can we view it as a graph and compute its topological invariants using topology of a graph?

Answer (score 2):

1. Consider a maximal tree $T$ in a connected graph $G$, then the map $G \to G/T$ is a homotopy equivalence and $G/T$ is a wedge of one-spheres.
2. The Euler characteristic is defined in many contexts, you don't need to have vector bundles on a manifold. For a finite graph, the Euler characteristic is simply the number of vertices minus the number of edges.
3. No, in a general cellular complex you have higher-dimensional cells. A graph is a one-dimensional CW complex, because you have only cells in dimension $0$ (corresponding to vertices) and cells in dimension $1$ (corresponding to edges)

Comment: Thank you. For 2, considering that we use wedge product of spheres to represent finite graph, why definitions of Euler characteristic using vector bundles on the wedge product of spheres and Euler characteristic on a finite graph are equivalent?

Comment: @threeautumn note that a wedge product of spheres is generally not a manifold and there is no natural vector bundle to consider. Let me be more explicit: there are many things called Euler characteristic and there's some relation between them, but that doesn't mean that everytime that there's something called a Euler characteristic, there has to be a vector bundle. The usual definition of the Euler characteristic is through homology, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2225039/348926 for how this relates to vector bundles.

Comment: Thank you. I got to know why we need cell complex for topology. We can use homology group of celluar complex to define characteristic class of wedge product of spheres rather than use vector bundles.